# PHP check if point is inside a circle

Tags: php

I have codes below

**circle.php**

```
class point{
    private $x;
    private $y;

    function __construct($x, $y){
        $this->x = $x;
        $this->y = $y;
    }

    public function getX(){
        return $this->x;
    }

    public function getY(){
        return $this->y;
    }

}

class circle{
    private $x_circle;
    private $y_circle;
    private $radius;

    function __construct($x_circle, $y_circle, $radius){
        $this->x_circle = $x_circle;
        $this->y_circle = $y_circle;
        $this->radius = $radius;
    }

    public function getCircleX(){
        return $this->x_circle;
    }

    public function getCircleY(){
        return $this->y_circle;
    }

    public function getRadius(){
        return $this->radius;
    }

    public function checkIfInside(){
        if(pow(getX() - getCircleX(), 2) + pow(getY() - getCircleY(), 2) < pow(getRadius(),2)){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
       
    }
}
```

**index.php**

```
include 'circle.php';

$point= new point(3, 4);
$circle= new circle(10, 10, 100);
$circle->checkIfInside();
```

I try to check if point is inside a circle. With point class we declare point coordinates(x,y). With circle class we declare the coordinates of circle(x,y) and radius. But I get this error: **Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function getX()**

Comment: Well, you need to pass the point into the circle. And then you need to call the getX on the point instead of on nothing.

Comment: How would your `checkIfInside()` function know which point you're talking about? So pass the point in the function `checkIfInside($point)` and then use `$point->getX()` and `$point->getY()`

Comment: Note that you can also use a Point instance to define the center, and add a "distanceFrom" method to the Point class: see https://3v4l.org/PheV9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix your `checkIfInside` function. It should receive a point as an argument. Also it lacks `$point` and `$this` references when calling methods.

```
public function checkIfInside($point) {
    return pow($point->getX() - $this->getCircleX(), 2) + pow($point->getY() - $this->getCircleY(), 2) < pow($this->getRadius(),2))      
}
```

Also, you should pass the point as an argument in your main code.

```
include 'circle.php';

$point = new point(3, 4);
$circle = new circle(10, 10, 100);
$circle->checkIfInside($point);
```

Answer (score 1):

The main issues:

- in `checkIfInside` *methods* are called as if they are global functions. You should instead include the object on which the method should be called, using the `->` notation. For instance, it should not be `getCircleX()`, but `$this->getCircleX()`
- This function should know which point you want to check with, so it should be an argument: `public function checkIfInside($point)`. The caller should pass this as argument in the call.
- Not a problem, but `if (boolean) { return true; } else { return false; }` is an anti-pattern. Just return the boolean.

Corrected method:

```
    public function checkIfInside($point){
        return pow($point->getX() - $this->getCircleX(), 2) + pow($point->getY() - $this->getCircleY(), 2) 
            < pow($this->getRadius(),2);
    }
```

Corrected call in main program:

```
$result = $circle->checkIfInside($point);
```

Answer (score 0):

`getX()` is not a global function, but a method of the `point` class. Methods must be called as `$object->method()`. (While inside a method such as `checkIfInside()`, the reference to the current object is `$this`.)

The same applies to the other methods you are calling in the statement below:

```
if(pow(getX() - getCircleX(), 2) + pow(getY() - getCircleY(), 2) < pow(getRadius(),2)){
```